# mac permission download folder ls folder

Tags: macos, directory, download, permissions

I can't `ls` my `/Users/alex/Downloads` folder.

- Other folders work normal.
- `touch blub.txt` works.
- via finder I see everything.

Permission are as followed:

```
613923      0 drwx---r-x@    4 alex  staff   128B 29 Jan 22:21 Downloads
```

I don't understand the behaviour.

[image]

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage; [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for questions like this... but you don't have to ask, it's already covered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375034/operation-not-permitted-for-root-when-trying-to-ls-or-chmod-r-users-user-des) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers) (tldr: you need to grant the Terminal app access to your "personal" files).

Comment: many tnx, it works. next time i only go for programming questions here.